# PHP ftp_login warns "You will be disconnected after 10 minutes of inactivity"

Tags: php, authentication, ftp

I wrote this script for connection to an FTP server

```
$ftp_server = 'ftp.xxx.com';
$ftp_user_name = 'myusername';
$ftp_user_pass = 'mypassword';

$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server,21);
if ($conn_id)
{
    echo("Connected to FTP<br><br>");
}
else
{
    echo("Connection error<br>");
}
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);
var_dump($login_result);
```

I see correctly *"Connected to server FTP"* but after I have this error

> Warning: ftp_login(): You will be disconnected after 10 minutes of inactivity.

I haven't firewall active.

I can login with FileZilla:

```
2021-06-24 11:58:24 72106 1 Status: Resolving address of ftp.cuimhni.it
2021-06-24 11:58:24 72106 1 Status: Connecting to 62.149.141.10:21...
2021-06-24 11:58:24 72106 1 Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
2021-06-24 11:58:24 72106 1 Response: 220-#
2021-06-24 11:58:24 72106 1 Response: 220-#                                 
2021-06-24 11:58:24 72106 1 Response: 220-#  Aruba.it                    
2021-06-24 11:58:24 72106 1 Response: 220-#  The Web Hosting Company     
2021-06-24 11:58:24 72106 1 Response: 220-#                                 
2021-06-24 11:58:24 72106 1 Response: 220-#
2021-06-24 11:58:24 72106 1 Response: 220 This is a private system - No anonymous login
2021-06-24 11:58:24 72106 1 Command: AUTH TLS
2021-06-24 11:58:24 72106 1 Response: 234 AUTH TLS OK.
2021-06-24 11:58:24 72106 1 Status: Initializing TLS...
2021-06-24 11:58:24 72106 1 Status: Verifying certificate...
2021-06-24 11:58:26 72106 1 Status: TLS connection established.
2021-06-24 11:58:26 72106 1 Command: USER 1515289@aruba.it
2021-06-24 11:58:26 72106 1 Response: 331 User 1515289@aruba.it OK. Password required
2021-06-24 11:58:26 72106 1 Command: PASS **************
2021-06-24 11:58:26 72106 1 Response: 230-Your bandwidth usage is restricted
2021-06-24 11:58:26 72106 1 Response: 230 OK. Current restricted directory is /
2021-06-24 11:58:26 72106 1 Command: SYST
2021-06-24 11:58:26 72106 1 Response: 215 UNIX Type: L8
2021-06-24 11:58:26 72106 1 Command: FEAT
2021-06-24 11:58:26 72106 1 Response: 211-Extensions supported:
2021-06-24 11:58:26 72106 1 Response:  UTF8
2021-06-24 11:58:26 72106 1 Response:  EPRT
2021-06-24 11:58:26 72106 1 Response:  IDLE
2021-06-24 11:58:26 72106 1 Response:  MDTM
2021-06-24 11:58:26 72106 1 Response:  SIZE
2021-06-24 11:58:26 72106 1 Response:  MFMT
2021-06-24 11:58:26 72106 1 Response:  REST STREAM
2021-06-24 11:58:26 72106 1 Response:  MLST type*;size*;sizd*;modify*;UNIX.mode*;UNIX.uid*;UNIX.gid*;unique*;
2021-06-24 11:58:26 72106 1 Response:  MLSD
2021-06-24 11:58:26 72106 1 Response:  PRET
2021-06-24 11:58:26 72106 1 Response:  AUTH TLS
2021-06-24 11:58:26 72106 1 Response:  PBSZ
2021-06-24 11:58:26 72106 1 Response:  PROT
2021-06-24 11:58:26 72106 1 Response:  ESTA
2021-06-24 11:58:26 72106 1 Response:  PASV
2021-06-24 11:58:26 72106 1 Response:  EPSV
2021-06-24 11:58:26 72106 1 Response:  SPSV
2021-06-24 11:58:26 72106 1 Response:  ESTP
2021-06-24 11:58:26 72106 1 Response: 211 End.
2021-06-24 11:58:26 72106 1 Command: OPTS UTF8 ON
2021-06-24 11:58:26 72106 1 Response: 504 Unknown command
2021-06-24 11:58:26 72106 1 Command: PBSZ 0
2021-06-24 11:58:26 72106 1 Response: 200 PBSZ=0
2021-06-24 11:58:26 72106 1 Command: PROT P
2021-06-24 11:58:26 72106 1 Response: 200 Data protection level set to "private"
2021-06-24 11:58:26 72106 1 Status: Logged in
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you login with FileZilla, it uses encrypted FTPS connection.

To do the same in PHP, use [`ftp_ssl_connect`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-ssl-connect.php), instead of `ftp_connect`.